# How to format links in comments

Tags: support, comment, markdown, hyperlinks

I wonder how to provide nice links in comments, similar to the links in the question/answers. I tried

```
<a href="link">link description</a>
```

and

```
[link description][1]
[1]: link
```

so far, but neither works as desired. Still, there must be a way to do it, because many users regularly provide nicely formatted links in their comments.

Comment: See [How do you cite a reference in a comment?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/how-do-you-cite-a-reference-in-a-comment).

Comment: Please clear the sandbox if you are done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Markdown's inline link syntax, an example of which is shown when you click the "help" link under "Add Comment".

```
[link text](http://link-uri.com)
```

This works in answers as well.